# Populating with records on Html Table

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

A php custom function returns record set from a mysql query.

I need to populate a two column table having equal quantity or balanced between two.

I know we can split by number of columns the row count then use a loop to populate each td accordingly.

Any suggestions or most practical way to display record sets onto tables organized according to their sizes?

Not using templates at this time.

Basically need to control the TD tag from been echo or not and filled.

**Sample Code:**

```
$col_num = 2; //Number of colums to parse data onto.

$count_r = mysql_num_rows($result)/$col_num;

echo '<table style="width:400px;border:3px solid green;"><tr><td>'; 

$ui=1;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{                            
    if($ui<$count_r)
        {

            echo '<input disabled type="checkbox" value="$row[id]"'; $this->ischecked($uid,$row[id]); echo "/>".$row['name'].'<br>'."\r\n";

        }
    $ui++;
} 

//FIRST COLUMN SET

echo '</td>';

echo '<td>';

//SECOND COLUMN SET


echo '</td></tr></table>';
```

Comment: Does it matter if the records are listed in order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind about the order of your records you could simply do (assuming you've got your results in an array called `$result`) the following:

```
...
echo "<table>";
for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i+=2):
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>{$result[$i]['field']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$result[$i+1]['field']}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
endfor;
echo "</table>";
```

I don't know if it's the best way of doing this but it's the way I'd do it in your case. Keep in mind that I'm not checking if there are any actual results, we are assuming that it's the case. To check if `$results` is set you could use an `if` statement checking it's count number for example.

*Note*
Replace `for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i+=2):` with `for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i+=2){` and `endfor;` with `}` for a traditionally formatted code.

Comment: Thanks. The example opened up my head a bit and I was able to complete the function.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using an unordered list -- `<ul>`, and apply the CSS `float` attribute to its list items (`<li>`). That way, you won't have to worry about counting the number of records.

Just output each record in a `<li>`, and set them all to `float: left;`.

Then constrain the height of the `<ul>` so it will be short enough to force the extra `<li>`s to float to a new column.

As @Steve pointed out, you'll also need to set the `<li>` width to be constant so the columns will be consistent. And make the width of your `<ul>` more than twice and less than three times as big as the `<li>` width.

A basic way to do that would be to call `mysql_num_rows()` on your query. Multiply the result by the height of each `<li>`, then divide by two, and that will be the height of your `<ul>`. That will make each column of equal height.

You *could* also do it with `<div>`s (one `<div>` for each item, all wrapped in a single global `<div>`).

But using a list is the preferred way of displaying a list of information in HTML (unless the information is tabular in nature and requires multiple columns per field, which yours isn't and doesn't).

If you need more detailed help, there's a [great Opera Web Standards article](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/32-styling-lists-and-links/#fauxcolumns) on this.

Comment: Don't forget to set the width of your `LI`s to maintain standard column width.  Otherwise, they'll only fit the text, so will not all be the same size.

Comment: @Steve: Yeah, definitely. I forgot to mention that.